# Can a Trade-related arrow be only at the chart that has opened / closed the trade, while multiple charts of the same currency pair are present in MT5?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

[MT5] How to display the arrow only at the chart that has opened a position - closed position ( Show realtime history of deals on chart ), so that other charts will not allow to display the arrow.

I open multiple charts of the same currency pair ( using different time frames or same time frame ) and run a robot on each of them.
When one chart opens a position or closes a position, it will show synchronously an arrow on all other charts. Is that synchronous displaying of arrows a default MT5 behaviour?

How to display the arrow only at the chart that has opened a position - closed a position?

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.
[image]

I want to show the arrow as on the MT4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### No.

This seems to be a default & hard-coded behaviour of the MetaTrader Terminal 5.

Hard-coded MetaTrader Terminal 4 / 5 GUI-operations have zero freedom of configuration ( as of 2017-05 ).

### Any workaround?

Yes, one may resort to implement a graph-specific GUI-object in the Expert Advisor ( robot ), thus such a marker would appear only in such the graph-window, which was placing the respective XTO-operation, be it { entry | modification | exit }.

---

### Warning:

One might be already aware, that recent language updates have enabled risks from a quite wild range of behaviours, where a code, running on a GUI-graph-A ( i.e. USDCAD ) may intervene into the graph-scene inside whatever else GUI-graph-X's context, just by mis-using **`ChartID()` for a "Hostile takeover" via `ChartNavigate()`**, can remote-generate **`ObjectCreate()`**, remote-change **`ObjectSet()`**, {remote|self}-switch both the symbol & period (!!!!!) **`ChartSetSymbolPeriod()`** or even delete remote-objects or even kill the remote-graph, or commit a suicside call on self by a **`ChartDelete()`**...

Only the thorough code-review, line by line is a sort of chance to survive this freedom to destroy via *New*-MQL4.56789 commands having now the same power as WMD.